# Set itemSize of UICollectionViewFlowLayout based on screen size

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8

I have a 'UICollectionView' that I use to horizontally paginate many items one at a time by subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

For that I have set insets on both sides and have an override for `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset(: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint` method to keep the item always at the center of screen.

Then to have the cell fill the entire screen but let just a hint of the previous and next cells on screen like this:

```
|-------------------|
|-| |-----------| |-|
|x| |xxxxxxxxxxx| |x|
|x| |xxxxxxxxxxx| |x|
|x| |xxxxxxxxxxx| |x|
|x| |xxxxxxxxxxx| |x|
|x| |xxxxxxxxxxx| |x|
|-| |-----------| |-|
|-------------------|
```

To have that I set the `itemSize` on `prepareLayout`:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
  let spacingConstant: CGFloat = 16.0
  self.minimumLineSpacing = spacingConstant * 2
  self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: spacingConstant * 3, bottom: 30, right: spacingConstant * 3)
  self.scrollDirection = .Horizontal
}
override func prepareLayout() {
  super.prepareLayout()
  if let mySize = self.collectionView?.frame {
    let size = CGSize(
      width: mySize.width - self.sectionInset.right - self.sectionInset.left,
      height: mySize.height - self.sectionInset.top - self.sectionInset.bottom
    )
    self.itemSize = size
  }
}
```

But I keep getting warnings that the itemSize must be less than view's height minus insets, which exactly what I am doing here.

```
the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.
```

What's the best approach to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I got another warning which helped me, and apparently will help you:

> the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView
>   minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the **content
>   insets** top and bottom values.

Just add the following:

```
let size = CGSize(
      width: mySize.width - self.sectionInset.right - self.sectionInset.left - self.collectionView!.contentInset.left - self.collectionView!.contentInset.right,
      height: mySize.height - self.sectionInset.top - self.sectionInset.bottom - self.collectionView!.contentInset.top - self.collectionView!.contentInset.bottom
    )
```